# gitlab-ci - repo with 2 branches, 2 gitlab-ci

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm crash coursing myself on GitLab and trying to understand how the CI features work.
I've noticed that it allows you to have a GitLab-ci.yml per branch in a given repo.  I've also just learned about the "only" keyword that allows me to limit the scope of a specific job to a particular branch.

But I have the following questions.

1. If you don't have any "only" clauses, and the pipeline triggers, can i assume that the GitLab-ci.yml that will run is the one that's associated with the branch that just committed a change?
2. is there any scenario when a single GitLab-ci.yml without an only clause runs against multiple branches in a repo?

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline will be only trigger on the branch you committed except if you explicit use trigger keyword to trigger other projects or branches. Keyword like only, except, rules are used as conditions to run a specific step. By exemple, you can use only master for your deploy-production step.